# Automated CAGR Calculation Based on Column Titles in R

Tags: r, function, loops, data.table

I have a dataset that has revenue data across multiple brands and years in columns. Each column name has Brandname.yr for 09-12. Some brands only have data for 10-12 or 11-12. I have developed the following code to calculate CAGR for each client in each brand. However when I execute the code my CAGrs are in the thousands (i.e 4800.74). Does anyone have any suggestions for why the CAGR calculation isn't executing properly?

Data Example.

```
ClientID    Rv.Brand1.09    Rv.Brand1.10    Rv.Brand1.11    Rv.Brand1.12    Rv.Brand2.09    Rv.Brand2.10    Rv.Brand2.11    Rv.Brand2.12
1   6991979 6931508 5071305 4944208 2079843 2990803 2111142 1977724
2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
3   0   29425   0   0   0   29425   0   0
4   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
5   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0




library(data.table)
dataset <- data.table(mdb)
# Getting the list of column names for which CAGR needs to be calculated
Instance09 = gsub(
  colnames(dataset)[
    grepl(colnames(dataset), pattern = ".09")
    ], 
  pattern = ".09", 
  replacement = ""
)

Instance10 = gsub(
  colnames(dataset)[
    grepl(colnames(dataset), pattern = ".10")
    ], 
  pattern = ".10", 
  replacement = ""
)

Instance11 = gsub(
  colnames(dataset)[
    grepl(colnames(dataset), pattern = ".11")
    ], 
  pattern = ".11", 
  replacement = ""
)

Instance12 = gsub(
  colnames(dataset)[
    grepl(colnames(dataset), pattern = ".12")
    ], 
  pattern = ".12", 
  replacement = ""
)

Instance0912 <- intersect(Instance09,Instance12)

Instance1012 <- intersect(Instance10,Instance12)

Instance1112 <- intersect(Instance11,Instance12)

Instance1012 <- Instance1012[!Instance1012 %in% Instance0912]

Instance1112 <- Instance1112[!Instance1112 %in% Instance0912]

for ( i in Instance0912 )
{
  #calculating CAGR for each i
  #dataset is a data.table and not a data.frame
  dataset[, 
          paste0("CAGR",i):= (get(paste0(i,".12")) / get(paste0(i,".09")) ^ (1/3)) - 1
          ]

}

for ( i in Instance1012 )
{
  #calculating CAGR for each i
  #dataset is a data.table and not a data.frame
  dataset[, 
          paste0("CAGR",i):= (get(paste0(i,".12")) / get(paste0(i,".10")) ^ (1/2)) - 1
          ]

}

for ( i in Instance1112 )
{
  #calculating CAGR for each i
  #dataset is a data.table and not a data.frame
  dataset[, 
          paste0("CAGR",i):= (get(paste0(i,".12")) / get(paste0(i,".11")) ^ 1) - 1
          ]

}
```

Comment: Is this a _minimal_ example; i.e., is all the code here really necessary to demonstrate your question? Which line of code generates 4800.74; i.e., can you include the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put an extra set of parenthesis when you calculate the CAGR, like this for the first case:

```
for ( i in Instance0912 )
{
#calculating CAGR for each i
#dataset is a data.table and not a data.frame
dataset[, 
        paste0("CAGR",i) := ((get(paste0(i,".12")) / get(paste0(i,".09"))) ^ (1/3)) - 1
        ]

}
```

You should be careful in the grepl(), in regex a dot `.` matches any character. You need to write it as `\.` to match a dot literally. Not a problem in the concrete case, just be aware of it.

I would also recommend to think about reorganizing your data in a long format, and possibly define a function to calculate the CAGR (to avoid technical mistakes in spelling out the same calculation for different months.